# How to get a TestServer to use a different appsettings file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, structuremap

This is a pretty weird problem I'm having. I'm trying to set up a `TestServer` to test an ASP.NET API. In this particular test, instead of the `appsettings.json` of the project, I want to use a different config, `appsettings.custom.json`. So, when I create my `TestServer`, here's what I do:

```
protected TestServer CreateTestServer()
{
    var testConfiguration = new AspNetTestConfiguration(); // configures middleware, authentication, default/static files
    var configFile = "appsettings.custom.json";
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile(configFile).Build();
    Container.Configure(cfg => cfg.For<IConfiguration>().Use(config)); // attempt 1 - that's my StructureMap container used for DI

    // Create the WebHostBuilder used by the test server
    var webHostBuilder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                                .ConfigureServices(svc =>
                                                   {
                                                       svc.AddSingleton(Container);
                                                       svc.AddSingleton(config); // attempt 2
                                                       svc.AddSingleton(testConfiguration);
                                                   })
                                .UseConfiguration(config) // attempt 3
                                .UseStartup<TestStartup>();

    return new TestServer(webHostBuilder);
}
```

But then, when I get into my controller, which has an `IConfiguration` provided in the constructor through dependency injection, I access the settings in the `IConfiguration` and find that the values are the ones from `appsettings.json`!

As you can see above, I've tried 3 different ways to convince the `TestServer` that it must use config values from `appsettings.custom.json`, to no avail.

Why is it still insisting on using `appsettings.json`, and how do I fix it?

**UPDATE:**
Curiouser and curiouser. I tried renaming `appsettings.json` to `appsettings.default.json` and set that as my default settings file. Now, magically, my `TestServer` is using `appsettings.custom.json` where I expected it to!

Comment: The best way is to use the same config file and add options for testing.

Comment: I’d suggest you to use the WebApplicationFactory for [integration testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2) which also supports reconfiguring the application. – Things like custom middleware and services, and even a different startup are a very good way to make your tests not represent your application at all, so you should avoid doing that. Always test your actual application and only partially replace things if you _need_ to to make it work as a test.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you set the test json file to be copied to the output directory if newer

We use this for this situation in .NET Core 2.x

```
public class TestServerFixture : IDisposable
{
    private readonly TestServer _testServer;
    public HttpClient Client { get; }

    public TestServerFixture(string assemblyName)
    {

        IWebHostBuilder builder = new WebHostBuilder()
               .UseContentRoot(Path.Combine(ConfigHelper.GetSolutionBasePath(), assemblyName))
               .UseEnvironment("Development")
               .UseConfiguration(new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.tests.integration.json") //the file is set to be copied to the output directory if newer
                    .Build()
                ).UseStartup(assemblyName);

        _testServer = new TestServer(builder);

        Client = _testServer.CreateClient();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Client.Dispose();
        _testServer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

and to get the solution base path

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the current soution base path
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string GetSolutionBasePath()
{
    var appPath = PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;
    var binPosition = appPath.IndexOf("\\bin", StringComparison.Ordinal);
    var basePath = appPath.Remove(binPosition);

    var backslashPosition = basePath.LastIndexOf("\\", StringComparison.Ordinal);
    basePath = basePath.Remove(backslashPosition);
    return basePath;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am copying my config file to the output folder. See my update to the question please, for some interesting developments.

Comment: @ShaulBehr You probably didn’t rebuild the project properly enough before running your tests, which means that the new config wasn’t copied over.

Comment: @poke I deleted the `bin` folder and rebuilt the project. Didn't change the behavior. If the default file is called `appsettings.json`, then the custom `TestServer` attempts to use that config. If I name the default file something else, like `appsettings.default.json`, then everything works as expected. Repro every time.

Comment: @ShaulBehr this is because `appsettings.json` is the first name for the settings file and .NET Core looks for, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#default-configuration

Answer (score 1):

Daniel's answer is great, but I have a cleaner solution that does not need to specify explicitly which `appsettings.json` to use or tweak paths.

The most important thing to notice is that TestServer uses a `WebHostBuilder`, not a generic, and therefore you need to teach this `WebHostBuilder` how to read settings from json files, environment, secrets, etc. or it won't be able to.

This is valid for .NET Core 3.1+ (and .NET 5) and I use a similar approach as the accepted answer where my integration tests extend an abstract class that sets up everything for me.

```
public abstract class FunctionalTest
    : GivenAsync_WhenAsync_Then_Test
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    protected HttpClient HttpClient { get; }
    protected IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    protected FunctionalTest()
    {
        var server =
            new TestServer(
                new WebHostBuilder()
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .UseCommonConfiguration()
                    .UseEnvironment("Test")
                    .ConfigureTestServices(ConfigureTestServices));

        HttpClient = server.CreateClient();
        _serviceProvider = server.Services;
        Configuration = _serviceProvider.GetService<IConfiguration>();
    }

    protected T GetService<T>() where T : class
    {
        return _serviceProvider.GetService<T>();
    }

    protected virtual void ConfigureTestServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Here replace DI container registrations for test executions, 
        // although you can also do this at the specific test since this is a virtual method that can be overriden
    }
}
```

There are a few things to notice:

1. The `GivenAsync_WhenAsync_Then_Test` is just a custom simple abstract class I use to force me write the tests with a Given When Then approach. Irrelevant for this issue, but if you wanna have a look it's at https://gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/sasw-test-support
2. I have a custom extension method called `UseCommonConfiguration` that does all the heavy lifting to teach `IWebHostBuilder` how to read settings. The implementation is standard

   ```
   public static IWebHostBuilder UseCommonConfiguration(this IWebHostBuilder builder)
   {
      builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
      {
          var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;

          config
              .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
              .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
              .AddEnvironmentVariables();

          if (env.IsDevelopment())
          {
              var appAssembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(env.ApplicationName));
              config.AddUserSecrets(appAssembly, optional: true);
          }
      });

      return builder;
   }
   ```
3. I also set the Environment to `"Test"`, that way I am dealing just with a different environment for test executions, everything else is the same (Same `Startup` class as the real application, etc.). With this, I am telling AspNet Test Server to look for an `appsettings.Test.json`. So go ahead and have a specific `appsettings.Test.json` with the test values you want to use, and place it under the test project's root (if you want) with `BuildAction Content` and `Copy to Output Directory Copy if newer` (same properties as the standard `appsettings.json` or `appsettings.Development.json`
4. The line `ConfigureTestServices(sp => { /* .. */})` allows to replace/modify the DI container registrations that happen at Startup. Very usefult to replace some services with mocks or similar.

Then, your test classes can extend this abstract class `FunctionalTest` and have available the `HttpClient` to send http requests to the test server as in `_result = await HttpClient.PostAsync("api/whatever", myStringContent);`

Answer (score 0):

You can also inject values overriding appsettings:

```
        var testServer = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseEnvironment("NarrowIntegratedTest")
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
            {
                //Override appsettings values
                builder.AddInMemoryCollection(
                       new Dictionary<string, string>
                       {
                           ["ConnectionStrings:MyDB"] = "PROVIDE_VALUE"
                           ["PathXPTO"] = "PROVIDE_VALUE"
                       });
            })
            .UseStartup<WebAPI.Startup>());

        await testServer.Host.StartAsync();
        _client = testServer.CreateClient();
```